# Use Python OpenCV to Crop/Rotate/Resize Playing Cards From an Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV (using 3.4.1 on Python 2.7) and wanting to learn how to process an image containing 9 playing cards. I know how to read in the image and have seen some examples of image processing, but don't know where to go from there.

[image]

Ideally, I want to crop each of the nine cards from the image, rotate them to be completely straight (if offset), resize if needed, and save each card to a new image while retaining the color.

Any examples to get me in the right direction are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have detailed the steps needed to crop and align each individual card alongside the relevant code.

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#--- dimensions of the cropped and aligned card 
card_width = 140
card_height = 200

path = 'C:/Users/Jackson/Desktop/'
im = cv2.imread(path + 'cards.jpg')

#--- convert to grayscale ---
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#--- perform Otsu threshold to binarize the image (black and white) ---
ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(imgray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Result of the binary image:

[image]

Notice the white region surrounding the cards. We will use that to find all the cards and then extract them individually.

```
im2 = im.copy()

#--- only finding the external contours ---
_, contours, hierarchy =    cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

We are creating two separate functions here.

The first function is to get the corner points of each card after obtaining the bounding rectangle with minimum area:

```
def get_points(r):
    p1 = (abs(int(r[1][0]/2) - r[0][0]), abs(int(r[1][1]/2) - r[0][1]))
    p2 = (abs(int(r[1][0]/2) + r[0][0]), abs(int(r[1][1]/2) - r[0][1]))
    p3 = (abs(int(r[1][0]/2) - r[0][0]), abs(int(r[1][1]/2) + r[0][1]))
    p4 = (abs(int(r[1][0]/2) + r[0][0]), abs(int(r[1][1]/2) + r[0][1]))
    return p1, p2, p3, p4
```

The next function is to transform the cropped image to a proper aligned image using `cv2.warpPerspective()`. Prior to that the transformation matrix `M` is calculated using `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform()` which is used to form the aligned image. More on this topic [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html):

```
def perform_perspective(p1, p2, p3, p4, orig_im):
    pts_src = np.array([list(p1), list(p2), list(p3), list(p4)])
    pts_dst = np.array([[0.0, 0.0],[card_width, 0.0],[0.0, card_height],[card_width, card_height]])
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src.astype(np.float32), pts_dst.astype(np.float32))
    image = cv2.warpPerspective(orig_im, M, (card_width, card_height))
    return image
```

Notice in the function above I am resizing each card to dimension (140, 200). You can change it as you wish.

Now find each card, cropping and aligning them appropriately:

```
for cnt in contours:

    #--- just to ensure we do not capture unwanted shapes ---
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100):

        #--- getting the rectangular region around each card to see the cropped card ---
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        crop_img = im2[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow('crop_img', crop_img)

        #--- getting the minimum rectangle required to help align the card ---
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4 = get_points(rect)
        im_result = perform_perspective(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, im)
        cv2.imshow('im_result', im_result)

        cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Few Results:**

[image]  [image]  [image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted to retain the quality of the original image to the cropped card, could I send each bounding rectangle to crop with PIL?

Comment: To perform cropping you do not need PIL. It can be done using array slicing as in the code: `crop_img = im2[y:y+h, x:x+w]`.

Comment: Gotcha. This works really well! Another thing I was considering was making the initial bounding rectangle a hair bigger than the card itself to fully rotate and "center" the card, and then perform the final crop. "Center" in this case would mean the position of the top two corners form a straight line.

Comment: @alpacafondue A better idea though it would take some time to code it. That is why I opted to chose the rectangle with the minimum bounding area for each card and used those corner points instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Cropping**

As the images you loaded are nothing more than arrays you can also treat them as such and choose subarrays:

```js
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("photo.png")
x = 0
y = 0
width = 100
height = 100
cropped_img = img[y:y+height, x:x+width]
cv2.imshow("cropped_images", cropped_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Rotating**

To rotate the pictures you have to create a transformation matrix that is applied to the image

```js
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/home/arjun/Desktop/logos/python.png')
# get image height, width
(h, w) = img.shape[:2]
# calculate the center of the image
center = (w / 2, h / 2)

angle90 = 90

scale = 1.0

# Perform the counter clockwise rotation holding at the center
# 90 degrees
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle90, scale)
rotated90 = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (h, w))
cv2.imshow('rotated_image',rotated90)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Have fun while implementing ;)

Comment: When changing the scale in the second example you can resize the picture but you can also use cv2.resize(img, (target_width, target_height))